# iOS keyboard forces page scroll, is it possible to prevent the scroll event of iOS in javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I've got a navigation remaining fixed when the page is scrolled,, it includes a search field, but when I'm trying to focus on the field while the page is scrolled, the keyboard pops up and forces a page scroll to the  top of the page, and I'm not able to write anything there... I'd like to prevent that iOS autoscroll event..

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to focus it?

Comment: I meant when I touch on that field to start typing,  page scrolls to the top

Comment: Could you show us your code? That would be helpful